# Expression for when you ask a question for the sole reason of correcting someone's wrong answer

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

This question has been bothering me for quite some time, what do you call it when you ask a question knowing full well that the other person is going to say the wrong thing just so you can correct him, e.g.:

> Hey, what’s the capital of Brazil?
>   Other: Rio!
>   Me: Incorrect, it’s Brazillia!

Comment: Are you waiting for an incorrect answer? :)

Comment: I can only think of a 'trick question'.

Answer (score 1):

-Hey, what’s the capital of Brazil?

-Rio!

-***Gotcha***! It’s Brasilia!